# How to set the inactive color of the RadioListTile in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I set the active color in RadioLisTile

```
RadioListTile<EnumBuyItem>(
      title: Text(item.itemName, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
      value: item.itemValue,
      groupValue: selectedItem,
      onChanged: (EnumBuyItem value) { setState(() { selectedItem = value; }); },
      activeColor: Colors.red,
    ),
```

But I can't find the inactive color property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

In your `MaterialApp()` widget, add a [Material Color](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Colors-class.html) to `unselectedWidgetColor` property.
This will affect the entire application.

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
      unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.blue,
  ),
);
```

Comment: yes great solution thanks a lot really saved me

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to change it in a specific part of your application you can wrap your `RadioListTile`s within a [Theme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Theme-class.html) and specify the `unselectedWidgetColor` property:

---

```
Theme(
  data: myThemeData.copyWith(
    unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.grey,
  ),
  child: myRadioListTilesWidget,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to wrap your RadioListTile by this manner

```
               child: Theme(
                data: ThemeData(
                  unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.white,
                ),
                child: RadioListTile(
                  title: "Consent",
                   
                    value: false,
                    activeColor: Colors.white,
                    selectedTileColor: Colors.white,
                    groupValue: consentAcceptanceStatus,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        consentAcceptanceStatus = false;
                      });
                    }
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `fillColor:` property in `RadioListTile`

```
RadioListTile<EnumBuyItem>(
      title: Text(
        item.itemName,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      value: item.itemValue,
      groupValue: selectedItem,
      onChanged: (EnumBuyItem value) {
        setState(() {
          selectedItem = value;
        });
      },
      activeColor: Colors.red,

      /// This Line
      fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
        Colors.white,
      ),
    ),
```